# Java binary search without specific method

Tags: java

I have to create an ordered array of numbers. Next, I should enter a number and find it with the binary search.

I have seen that there is a very simple method (java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a, int key)), but I can not use it.

How can I do a binary search without this method? Thank you for your support.

For example, I have this array: A = [1, 5, 10, 21, 30, 50]
And I have to find the number 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your array and number to be searched in the following method

```
public int binarySearch(int arr[], int num) 
    { 
        int left = 0, right = arr.length - 1; 
        while (left <= right) { 
            int middle = left + (right - l) / 2; 

            if (arr[middle] == num) 
                return middle; 
            if (arr[middle] < num) 
                left = middle + 1; 
            else
                right = middle - 1; 
        } 
        return -1; 
    }
```

Also good explanation can be found at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/